# Batch file to merge all txt files in folder on beginning and end of each txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi guys I have folder with large number of txt files.

```
start.txt
end.txt
text1.txt
text2.txt
text3.txt
...
```

I need to create batch file/command who will merge files like this:

`start.txt -> text1.txt -> end.txt to text1.txt`

`start.txt -> text2.txt -> end.txt to text2.txt`

I can put start.txt and end.txt outside folder, so its easier to work with.

So my new text1.txt will look like:

text1.txt

> start.txt
>    text1.txt
>    end.txt

And so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need a batch file for that:

```
for %F in (*.txt) do copy ..\start.txt+%F+..\end.txt ..\new_%F
```

If used in a batch file you need to double the `%`:

```
for %%F in (*.txt) do copy ..\start.txt+%%F+..\end.txt ..\new_%%F
```